# $X$ a random variable, where $-1\leq X\leq \frac{1}{2}, \mathbb E[X]=0$. What is the maximal value of $\mathbb E[X^2]$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

$X$ a random variable, where $$-1\leq X\leq \frac{1}{2}, \mathbb E[X]=0$$

> Find the maximal value of $\mathbb E[X^2]$.

---

I came across a similar question, asking if the following  inequality is always true $$\mathbb E[X^2]\leq \frac{1}{4}$$

The answer is no, for example:
$$\mathbb P(X=-1) = \frac{1}{3},\mathbb P(X=\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{2}{3}\implies\\ \mathbb E[X^2]= ((-1)^2)\cdot(\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{2})^2\cdot(\frac{2}{3})=\\ \frac{1}{3} +\frac{2}{3\cdot 4} =\frac{1}{2}$$
I was wondering how can one find the maximum, for any discrete or continuos random variable.

---

**Remark:** I'm not sure this question has a "nice" solution.

Comment: can't this be posed as optimization with lagrange multipliers? we have one constraint $\int x dP = 0$, and have to maximize $\int x^2 dP$

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but I don't see exactly how, because I am trying to maximize **a function** ($X$), and not find a local maximum **of** a function on a boundary.

Comment: There are a few different names for this result -- sometimes Gruess's Inequality, sometimes Popviciu's Inequality.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable

Comment: Since $-1\le X\le 1/2$, you have $(X+1)(X-1/2)\le 0$ so that $$\Bbb{E}[(X+1)(X-1/2)\big]\le 0.$$  This should give you a bound of $\Bbb{E}[X^2]$ in terms of $\Bbb{E}[X]$, but then you know $\Bbb{E}[X]=0$.  The only thing left is to show that the bound obtained in this way is sharp, but then to get the maximum value, you need that $(X+1)(X-1/2)=0$ almost surely.

Comment: In general, let $m,\mu,M$ be real numbers such that $m\leq \mu \leq M$ and $m<M$.  If $X$ is a r.v. such that $m\le X\le M$ a.s. and $\Bbb{E}[X]=\mu$, then $$\operatorname{Var}[X]=\Bbb{E}\big[(X-\mu)^2\big]\le (\mu-m)(M-\mu),$$
or equivalently
$$\Bbb{E}[X^2]\le (\mu-m)(M-\mu)+\mu^2=(m+M)\mu-mM.$$  The equality holds iff $X\in\{m,M\}$ a.s. with $\Bbb{P}[X=m]=\frac{M-\mu}{M-m}$ and $\Bbb{P}[X=M]=\frac{\mu-m}{M-m}$.  From this, we can also prove Popoviciu's inequality $$\operatorname{Var}[X]\le \frac{(M-m)^2}{4}$$ which is an equality iff $X\in\{m,M\}$ a.s. and $\Bbb{P}[X=m]=\Bbb{P}[X=M]=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of generality say that $X\in [a,b]$ a.s. (this implies $a\leq 0$).
Since $X=\frac{b-X}{b-a}a + \frac{X-a}{b-a}b$ and the square function is convex, $X^2\leq \frac{b-X}{b-a}a^2 + \frac{X-a}{b-a}b^2$ and taking expectations, $$E(X^2)\leq \frac{b}{b-a}a^2 - \frac{a}{b-a}b^2 = -ab$$

This bound is tight: it is attained only for $X\sim \frac{b}{b-a} \delta_{a}+\frac{-a}{b-a} \delta_{b}$.

In the special case where $a=-1$ and $b=\frac 12$ this yields $E(X^2)\leq \frac 12$, with equality iff $X\sim \frac 13 \delta_{-1}+\frac 23 \delta_{1/2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \Bbb P(X < 0)\\
B &=& \Bbb P(X > 0)\\
C &=& -\Bbb E(X|X < 0)\cdot A\\
D &=& \Bbb E(X|X > 0)\cdot B\\
E &=& \Bbb E(X^2|X < 0) \cdot A\\
F &=& \Bbb E(X^2|X > 0) \cdot B.
\end{eqnarray*}
We then have:$$E \leq C \leq A$$$$F \leq \frac12D \leq \frac14B$$$$A + B \leq 1$$$$C = D$$ and we want to maximize $E + F$.

We see that $$1 \geq A + B \geq C + 2D = 3C$$ which implies $C \leq \frac 1 3$, and hence $$E + F \leq C + \frac 1 2 D = \frac 3 2 C \leq \frac 1 2.$$

The equality is obtained when $\Bbb P(X = -1) = \frac1 3$ and $\Bbb P(X = \frac 12) = \frac 2 3$.

Comment: I'd add that this is the answer one "intuitively" expects - to get $E(X^2)$ large you want to push the probability mass towards the end points of the interval, and $E(X) = 0$ with $X$ only taking values $1/2$ or $-1$ gives $P(X  = -1) = 1/3, P(X = 1/2) = 2/3$.